# kSend JSON to template using handlebars java and ratpac

Tags: java, json, ratpack, handlebars.java

I am creating a test application that simply creates a JSON representation of an object and sends it to the template, I then want to use the JSON in a a JS script on the front end. I am using Ratpack and Java Handlebars to do this.

Here is my Ratpack handler

```
class HighChartHandler extends InjectionHandler {

    void handle(Context ctx, TestDataJson testDataJson) {
        testDataJson.goals = 1000
        testDataJson.name = "Nick"
        def jsonData = json(testDataJson)
        ctx.render(handlebarsTemplate('highchartTest.html', model: jsonData))
    }
}
```

And then I try to simply render the data on the page using

```
<h1>Graph Test</h1>
<p>This is a WIP highchart test</p>
<p>{{model}}</p>
```

However I get this message :

ratpack.jackson.internal.DefaultJsonRender@467db85c

I want to simply render something like

```
{"name":"Forlan","goals":1000}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you're using, `Jackson.json(Object)` https://ratpack.io/manual/current/api/ratpack/jackson/Jackson.html#json-java.lang.Object- whose return type is of `JsonRender` https://ratpack.io/manual/current/api/ratpack/jackson/JsonRender.html

So when you're running it through the template, it's simply calling "JsonRender#toString()`which results in what you're seeing:`ratpack.jackson.internal.DefaultJsonRender@467db85c`

The `Jackson.json` method returns what is known in Ratpack as a `Renderer`. It tells Ratpack how to represent the Object that you've provided to the `Renderer`.

In order to produce json mixed with html, I would do something like this:

```
def jsonData = new groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(testDataJson)
ctx.render(handlebarsTemplate('highchartTest.html', model: [model: jsonData]))
```

I haven't tested this but it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use

```
<p>Name: {{name}}</p>
<p>Goals: {{goals}}</p>
```

instead of

```
<p>{{model}}</p>
```